# Unwanted commas in formatted bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm quite new to latex and related stuff but I cannot get one thing to work for me.

Consider the following bib entry:

```
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
```

I'm getting output in bibliography with (to me) irritating commas after surnames:

```
[2] Goossens, M., Mittelbach, F., and Samarin, A. The LaTeX Companion.
Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.
```

By any possibility is it some popular error, or would I have to dive into bst files to fix this? In this particular example I replaced the bst provided ( yes, i replaced style in .cls too) and it happened with .bst from folder I've found in Bibtex (`acm.bst`).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcomer to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex`?

Comment: First, teh commas you get between a person's last name and first name can be removed by changing the reference style. Second, the `and` in between two person's names would automatically become a comma. You would probably be fine after taking care of those.

Comment: @Andrew This will have no effect. For simple FirstName LastName `.bib` entries, either order in the `.bib` file will be fine. The issue is with the `.bst` file. The comma is not an error, it is simply a common way to format names. So the OP needs to find a style that suits them.

Comment: Please tell us how you would like the names to be formatted. Is it just the comma between the surname and the initial(s), or are there other stylistic issues you'd like to fix? Please also confirm that you're employing the `acm` bibliography style at present.

Comment: The only issue for me is comma between name and surname, separated authors are fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AlanMunn has already pointed out in a comment, the presence of a comma between an author's formatted surname and the initials of his/her given name(s) is *not* an error. Instead, it is actually a fairly common stylistic choice for displaying authors' names.

The preamble of the file `acm.bst` contains the following information:

> % ACM Transactions bibliography style (8-Dec-10 version)
>
> %    A lot like abbrv.bst, but names come out "Last, initials", and in \sc.
>
> %    Some dates are parenthesized.

Note that the comma feature and the fact that names are typeset in small-caps are mentioned explicitly.

Have you tried using the `unsrt` bib style yet? Aside: If you employ the `natbib` citation management package, you may want to use `unsrtnat` instead of `unsrt`. It's a reimplementation of the much older `unsrt` bib style, but with the ability to (a) process fields such as `url`, `issn`, and `isbn` and (b) produce authoryear-style citation callouts as well as the basic numeric-style call-outs.

---

Assuming that you wish to continue using the `acm` bibliography style and simply desire to have no commas between surnames and initials, I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find a copy of the file `acm.bst` in your TeX distribution.
- Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `acm-nocommas.bst`. Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `acm-nocommas.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In this file, locate the function called `format.names`. (In my copy of this file, the function starts of line 190.)
- In this function, locate the line

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  In case you're curious: `vv`, `ll`, and `jj` refer to the (unabbreviated) von, lastname (or surname), and junior components of a person's full name, while `f.` refers to the abbreviated given (or first) name component.
- Change this line to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{ f.}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Observe that *two changes* have been applied: (i) there's no longer a comma immediately before `f.` and (ii) the "junior component" is now placed last, still offset with a comma from the rest of the name. I think it's essential to set off any "junior component" in this manner.
- Save the file `acm-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your text distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{acm}` to `\bibliographystyle{acm-mod}`. Next, perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE and its output:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{latexcompanion,
  author       = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
  title        = "The \LaTeX{} Companion",
  year         = 1993,
  publisher    = "Addison-Wesley",
  address      = "Reading, Massachusetts",
}
@article{lucas-rapping:1969,
  author       = "Lucas, Jr., Robert E. and Leonard A. Rapping",
  title        = "Real Wages, Employment, and Inflation",
  journal      = "Journal of Political Economy",
  year         = 1969,
  volume       = 77,
  number       = 5,
  pages        = "721--754",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{acm-mod}

\begin{document}
\cite{latexcompanion}, \cite{lucas-rapping:1969}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: one more question, what is a recommended program to edit such files, I tried it yesterday and thought it was my fault but again changing only that function lead to "can't start a style-file command---line 1 " and "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed."

Comment: I tried and it seems that as soon as I open file with notepad it became corrupted.

Comment: ok nvm. SublimeText have no problems with proper formatting that one. Thanks!

Comment: @kolboc - Please see the posting [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5001) for choices for TeX-aware editing software. For what it's worth, in my opinion `notepad` is singularly *unsuited* for work with TeX and LaTeX. Do yourself a huge favor and start using a real editor.